# Changing Default Invoice Numbering for PayPal WPP

Tags: paypal

I've integrated the PayPal WPP Pro Payment Method into my Drupal 7 site and it's working ok. My invoices are starting at #1 however, and I'd like to change my invoice numbering system...anyone know how to change the default?

Comment: PayPal's Invoice IDs are formatted like this:  INV2-VMYW-LQKA-QBGC-6YDE.  Where exactly are seeing "1,2,3..."?  You can send your own invoice ID in the CreateAndSendInvoice request using the "invoice" parameter.  Is that what you're referring to?  If so, that would be up to you to set that to whatever you want.

Comment: @AndrewAngell My mistake. I mean the Order # (not the invoice #). In the email that Drupal sends the user it displays as 'order number 11'. I'd like to make it look/sound more professional to something like 'order number 'LWS011' or something like that. Maybe that's a drupal-specific setting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Machavity is correct except that with [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/invoicing/CreateAndSendInvoice_API_Operation/) the parameter is actually called `INVOICE`.

It sounds like Drupal must be using that with its own record IDs.  If that assumption is correct then you'll need to configure Drupal to set those IDs how you're wanting.  Whatever value you send in that parameter to PayPal is what will get used.

Answer (score 0):

When you send your [DoDirectPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) (or however you're sending it) there's a parameter called `INVNUM` you can pass. This value is defined by you and passed back to you as you sent it, but unlike `CUSTOM` it is shown to both you and the customer (if you're doing it in Express Checkout)